# JQuery toggleClass() on and then back off (or remove)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using an angular directive to have a left and right column of a page. `<left-column></left-column>` and `<right-column></right-column>`. When the user clicks an `<a href="#target1">Target 1</a>` then it finds the corresponding `<div id="target1">Target 1</div>` in the *right column*.

That works fine and what I'm trying to do now is after it's clicked the specific div's background should kind of flash or something, I have some css for it. So I want to toggle that css class, then a second later remove that class (or toggle it off).

I'm trying to use a `setTimeout()` function but it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

My **error** is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleClass' of undefined
```

My **js** is:

```
var highlight = {

    onReady: function() {

        $(document).on('click', 'left-column > div', function(event) {

            var id = $('a', this).attr('href').split('#');
            var target = $('right-column > div').find('#' + id[1]);

            target.toggleClass('gas');
            var junk = setTimeout(function(target) {
                target.toggleClass('gas');
            }, 1000);

            event.preventDefault();

        });

    }

};


$(document).ready(highlight.onReady);
```

Comment: Haha, nice, but not sure what you mean, is backOff() a real function?

Comment: Please post a fiddle, so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: No...the title was humerous

Comment: Try using `target[0].toggleClass('gas');` or `target.each(function(){$(this).toggleClass('gas')});`

Comment: Unrelated (kinda), if you get the anchor, you can just do `$('a', this).prop('hash')`. I believe that will include the `#`, so you wouldn't need to add it back. Also, since you're finding an ID, you can just use `$(id)` rather than `find`ing it in the column.

Comment: Check what target returns `console.log(target)`. Maybe you look for div's#id wrogly and target is undefined. Try `$('#'+id[1]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're expecting `target` as an argument in the callback passed to `setTimeout`, but aren't actually passing any arguments so the `target` local to the `setTimeout` callback hides (shadows) access to the `target` available in the outer scope.

Removing `target` from the callback parameters will fix your error:

```
var junk = setTimeout(function(/* remove target from here */) {
  target.toggleClass('gas');
}, 1000);
```

Or you can explicitly pass it if you'd like but it would be redundant since its already available:

```
var junk = setTimeout(function(target) {
  target.toggleClass('gas');
}, 1000, target); // <--- you can pass the target along here
```

Comment: Awesome, I guess when I originally created the function I over-thought things. (I'll accept your answer in a few moments when the system lets me.) Thanks!

Comment: No problem mate, glad to help out :)